# Counting Review; Discrete Structures

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have forgotten a lot of the counting portion of my discrete structures course and need some explanations how to count, maybe some general strategies on counting.

Some example questions I need explaining are

5. Consider strings consisting of n characters, each character being a, b, or c. Let Sn be the
   number of such strings of length n that do not contain the substring aa. Which of the
   following is true?

(a) $S_{n+1} = S_n + S_{n−1}$ for $n ≥ 2.$

(b) $S_{n+1} = 2 · S_n + S_{n−1}$ for $n ≥ 2.$

(c) $S_{n+1} = S_n + 2 · S_{n−1}$ for $n ≥ 2.$

(d) $S_{n+1} = 2 · Sn + 2 · S_{n−1}$ for $n ≥ 2.$

Have a feeling it is C

7. Consider 4 blue balls B1, B2, B3, B4 and 5 red balls R1, R2, R3, R4, R5. We pick 3 balls of
   the same color and arrange them on a horizontal line. (The order on the line matters.) How
   many arrangements are there?

(a) 64

(b) 74

(c) 84

(d) 94

if anyone can help explain these questions to me that would be appreciated!

Comment: Just a comment- it would probably be helpful to tag your post as "combinatorics" as well as "discrete-mathematics." That way, folks interested in combinatorics problems will be more likely to see your posts. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(7) This is the permutation problem. We have $P(4, 3) + P(5, 3)$, where $P()$ is the permutation function.

(6) Consider $S_{1} = 3$. This is pretty easy to see. For $S_{2}$ we have two cases: the first character is or is not an $a$. If it is not an $a$, we have $3$ options. Otherwise, we have two options. So $S_{2} = 8$.

Now for $S_{3}$. There are $3^{3}$ such strings of length $3$ over $\{a, b, c\}$. We use inclusion-exclusion to count $S_{3}$. So we subtract out two consecutive $aa$ substrings (so $aa\{a, b, c\}$ or $\{a, b, c\}aa$, and add back in $aaa$. So $S_{3} = 3^{3} - 2(3) + 1 = 22$. Notice $S_{3} = 2S_{2} + 2S_{1}$.

So the answer is (d).